# Excel VBA - add a value to a cell in a certain row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to Excel VBA and I'm trying to getting figure out certain things. I want to populate cells in a range `K26:K386` with a value that comes from cell `N47` (call it "Income)". The cell to be populated (among those rows in `K26:386`) is determined by a number in cell `N46` (call it "Month"). "Income" can be any figure. "Month" can be any figure from 1 to 360.

I want to plug in two inputs into cells `N47` and `N46` - income and the respective month - such that the respective cell in range `K26:K386` is populated with the "Income" value for the respective month from 1 to 360. Can somebody please advise? 
I only know how to populate a single cell like this:

```
Sub Ievietot()
    Dim Sum As Integer
    Sum = Range("N47").Value
    Range("K30").Value = Sum
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51824639/edit) your question to add sample data and expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use

```
Range("K26:K386").Cells(Range("N46").Value) = Range("N47").Value
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be done as follows:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim iMonthNum as Integer
    Dim income as Integer

    iMonthNum = Range("N46").Value
    income = Range("N47").Value
    Range("K" & (25 + iMonthNum)).Value = income
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but something was wrong with the last line, it wouldn't run properly.

Comment: Sorry - I'd used + rather than & to concatenate the string.